# Can you turn off titles in player names?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Can you turn off titles in player names? For example if my name is Akbar, I might have the options to add "Captain Akbar" or "Akbar, Black Bisector".

When I'm in a warzone, the titles make it difficult for me to match up the player on screen to the badge on the operations frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like [you can't currently turn off titles for other players](http://www.swtor.com/de/community/showthread.php?t=101379) (nothing about it in the [patch notes](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes) so far either).

You can of course turn off your own from the Character Sheet or turn off all names from Preferences.